# Como saber que botón fue presionado?

Tags: java

Algún código para saber que boton fue presionado. NOTA agrege 20 botones pero fueron por código y tienen evento de ActionListener para todos.

**Frame**

```
public class PA_17130062_Frame_04 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements 
MouseListener, ActionListener {

private JFileChooser jfch = new JFileChooser();
private Memoria memorama[] = new Memoria[20];

int arre[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int arreAux[] = new int[arre.length];
int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, cont = 0;//Variables para saber en que posicion estan los 2 números 

public PA_17130062_Frame_04() {
    initComponents();
    inciar();
}

public int[] mezclar(int bar[]) {
    int m = bar.length - 1;
    for (int r = m; r > 1; r--) {
        int alea = (int) Math.floor(r * Math.random());
        int temp = bar[r];
        bar[r] = bar[alea];
        bar[alea] = temp;
    }
    return (bar);
}

public void inciar() {
    int x = 30, y = 50;

    mezclar(arre);
    int pres = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < memorama.length; r++) {
        memorama[r] = new Memoria(arre[r]);

        memorama[r].setLocation(x, y);

        x += 100;
        if ((r + 1) % 5 == 0) {
            y += 100;
            x = 30;
        }

        memorama[r].addActionListener(this);
        add(memorama[r]);

        arre[r] = 0;
    }
    setSize(550, 550);

    intentos = 0;

    jLabIntento.setText(intentos + "");
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Memoria btn1 = (Memoria) ae.getSource();
    Memoria btn2 = (Memoria) ae.getSource();

    btn2 = btn1;

    btnu = btn1;
    btnd = btn2;

    btnHabilitar(btnd);

    valor = valor(btn2);
    cont = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < memorama.length; r++) {
        if (valor == memorama[r].getNumero()) {
            if (cont == 0) {
                x1 = r;
                cont++;
            }
            x2 = r;
        }
    }

    jLabprueba.setText(btn1.getActionCommand() + "        " + memorama[x1].getNumero() + "|x1=" + x1
            + "     " + memorama[x2].getNumero() + "|x2=" + x2);
}
```

**Clase**

```
class Memoria extends JButton {
private int numero;

public Memoria (int num){
    numero = num;

    setSize(80,80);
    setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,34));
}

public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}
public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public void mostrarNumero() {
    setText(numero + "");
}

public void noMostrarNumero() {
    setText("");
}
```

}

[image: Así es como se ordenan mediante el código y que al seleccionar un botón saber que posición es,]

Comment: JarhChuy, publica el codigo con el que generas los botones e incluye mas detalles de lo que deseas.

Comment: Que exactamente hace la clase `Memoria`? Genera un button?

Comment: Basicamente solo le doy el tamaño al boton y modifico los atributos de Font igual te la pongo.

Comment: Ahora aclara algo, a que te refieres cuando dices que quieres saber que boton fue precionado? Osea, que tiene que pasar cuando se le de clic a cierto boton?

Comment: Es un memorama al presionarlo se tiene que mostraar un numero esta aleatorio. Yo solo quiero saber que boton presiono de los 20 que cree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu método actionPermormed "ae.getSource()" te devuelve el objeto que activa el evento. Ten en cuenta que esté método se implementa por la interface ActionListener y se lanza cada vez que se le da clic a un objeto agregado al ActionListener.

```
//Aqui instanciamos los botones
Button miBoton1 = new Button("Boton 1");
Button miBoton2 = new Button("Boton 2");
Button miBoton3 = new Button("Boton 3");

public miContructor(){
  //Aqui agregamo los botones al ActionListener
  miBoton1.addActionListener(this);
  miBoton2.addActionListener(this);
  miBoton3.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if(ae.getSource()==miBoton1){
      JOpitionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se presiono botón 1");
    }else if(ae.getSource()==miBoton2){
      JOpitionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se presiono botón 2");
    }else if(ae.getSource()==miBoton3){
      JOpitionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se presiono botón 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona Muchas Gracias :) :3